# Encode file to base64 in v-file-input vuejs and vuetify

Tags: vue.js, file-upload, vuejs2, base64, vuetify.js

vuetify:

```
 <v-file-input 
     multiple 
     label="Angebotsdokumente" 
     v-model="orderattachment">
</v-file-input>
```

How can I encode the file to base64?

Comment: Well, I do not know what variable contains my file object. `orderattachment` contains: `lastModified: 1575018339000
​​
name: "boarding-pass.pdf"
​​
size: 192624
​​
type: "application/pdf"
​​
webkitRelativePath: ""`   So is this the variable I need to convert?

Comment: The return type from the Change event for v-file-input is File[] - which is just an array of File objects. You can see this in the documentation by selecting Events in the API section and looking for the Change event: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/file-inputs. So in short, yes, that's what you'd need to convert.

Answer (score 1):

Easy.

1. Put a watch on your v-model object "orderattachment"
2. Run FileReader() on it and output the base64

```
watch: {
    orderattachment(value) {
      console.log("value", value)
      let fr = new FileReader()
      fr.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
        //this is your base64
        console.log(e.target.result)
      });
      fr.readAsDataURL(value)
    }
  },
```